# Docker Desktop k8s vpnkit-controller Always restart

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

```
level=error 
msg="Port 80 for service ingress-nginx-controller is already opened by another service
```

I tried to reset k8s. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Attempts to replace any port still show this error

Comment: Something else on your host has port 80 open. How are we to know what that is? Are you sure you don't already have another instance of the container running?

Comment: reflector.go:334] github.com/moby/vpnkit/go/cmd/kube-vpnkit-forwarder/main.go:49: watch of *v1.Service ended with: The resourceVersion for the provided watch is too old.
2023-05-18 14:38:59 log: exiting because of error: log: cannot create log: open /tmp/kube-vpnkit-forwarder.vpnkit-controller.unknownuser.log.WARNING.20230518-063859.1: no such file or directory

Comment: Did you solve the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have another process that is using port 80.

Check the service that is using the port 80

- on Linux `netstat -aon | grep :80`
- on Windows `netstat -aon | findstr :80`

and terminate it:

- on Linux: `pkill <pid>`
- on Windows kill the process with the specific `pid` from the `TaskManager`

Comment: level=error msg="Port 30001 for service order-svc is already opened by another service
k8s_vpnkit-controller prints that the port is occupied whenever any port is enabled

Comment: com.docker.backend.exe       11536 Console                    2     94,196 K
wslhost.exe                  19968 Console                    2      6,104 K
The occupied process is them

Comment: Have you tried to stop them? Did you fix your issue?